# Rewrite URL to exclude Django application name

Tags: django, apache, .htaccess, url, routes

on my live server, I am trying to remove/rewrite the need to include the application name in the URL, as without it I get a 404. For example:

`http://www.example.com/myapp/page.html`
to
`http://www.example.com/page.html`

This is especially tricky since i don't want this to affect the django admin URL which excludes the app name.

This is on Apache Server on Ubuntu on a shared host (A2).

Comment: what is your urls.py?

Comment: This is my main (non app specific) URLS.py:

'from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
 url(r'^drdotcom/', include('drdotcom.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're root urls.py most likely looks something like this:

```
"""
Definition of urls for api.
"""

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls'))
]
```

When you just replace `r'^myapp/'` with `r'^'` the app will be automatically tried, when there is nothing else before that fits (so it's best to put it to the end of the list)